how to upgrade to clang 16 in macOS
The current clang version is 14 in my macOS 13.3.1 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a):
> clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

I want to upgrade the clang to 16, then I tried like this followed https://ports.macports.org/port/clang-16/:
> sudo port install clang-16
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for clang-16
--->  Cleaning clang-16
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
--->  No broken ports found.

but the clang version is still 14, what should I do to upgrade the clang to 16?  I also tried like this:
> brew upgrade clang
==> Auto-updating Homebrew...
Adjust how often this is run with HOMEBREW_AUTO_UPDATE_SECS or disable with
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE. Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).

You have 45 outdated formulae and 6 outdated casks installed.

Error: No available formula with the name "clang". Did you mean cln, cling, clean, vlang, clingo or clac?

what should I do to upgrade the clang? should I upgrade the macOS operation system to the newest version? This is the macPorts clang path /opt/local/bin:
> ls *clang*
clang++-mp-16                  clang-cpp-mp-16                clang-include-fixer-mp-16      clang-offload-packager-mp-16   clang-reorder-fields-mp-16     clangd-mp-16
clang-apply-replacements-mp-16 clang-doc-mp-16                clang-linker-wrapper-mp-16     clang-pseudo-mp-16             clang-repl-mp-16               clangd-xpc-test-client-mp-16
clang-change-namespace-mp-16   clang-extdef-mapping-mp-16     clang-move-mp-16               clang-query-mp-16              clang-scan-deps-mp-16          git-clang-format-mp-16
clang-check-mp-16              clang-format-mp-16             clang-mp-16                    clang-refactor-mp-16           clang-tblgen-mp-16             run-clang-tidy-mp-16
clang-cl-mp-16                 clang-include-cleaner-mp-16    clang-offload-bundler-mp-16    clang-rename-mp-16             clang-tidy-mp-16

there seems no clang. This is the current clang path:
> whereis clang
clang: /usr/bin/clang /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man/man1/clang.1


Note that Apple's clang is not exactly the same as the open source release.

how to upgrade the apple's clang? is it possible to ugprade the clange verison to 16? or should I upgrade my operation system version?

Apple's clang version is included in Xcode (and CLT), so in order to upgrade it you need to upgrade Xcode. Xcode 15.4 (which is the most recent version) includes clang 15.

You might need https://ports.macports.org/port/clang_select/ and https://ports.macports.org/port/cctools/ as well, probably.

I need at least clang 16.

@Dolphin why do you need clang-16 - the reason does matter. If llvm version then don't use Xcode the project will include a build script.

@Dolphin You don't need or want to upgrade Apple's clang, you just need to install the one you want to use in another prefix.  I put an answer in your other question detailing how to select between them.

Also pointing out that in your example of ls *clang*, obviously clang 16 is there.

clang --version is showing it using the macOS built in clang. Make sure your MacPorts installed tools are before the Xcode toolchain on your PATH per the MacPorts installation instructions.

I have tried to export the path like this: export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

This will affect use of clang in terminal but probably not in Xcode

this did not change the clang version in terminal, it still use the old version, not the new version of clang.

@Dolphin it will - what does echo $PATH show?

Assuming that you installed clang correctly, the following path will lead you to clang- /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin .
